# Separate Model with List

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, asp.net-core-mvc, nest

I want to return a list of links to a web page when it loads. Right now I have a model called SsoLink.cs bound to the page. I would like to return a list, so I have created another model called SsoLinks.cs that has a List. In my helper function, I keep getting "object not set to an instance of an object".

SsoLink.cs

```
public class SsoLink
{
    public enum TypesOfLinks
    {
        [Display(Name="Please Select a Type")]
        Types,
        Collaboration,
        [Display(Name="Backups & Storage")]
        Backups_Storage,
        Development,
        [Display(Name="Cloud Services")]
        Cloud_Services,
        [Display(Name="Human Resources")]
        Human_Resources,
        Analytics
    }

    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public string Owner { get; set; }
    public string OwnerEmail { get; set; }
    public string LinkDescription { get; set; }
    public TypesOfLinks LinkType { get; set; }
}
```

SsoLinks.cs

```
public class SsoLinks
{
    public List<SsoLink> Links {get; set;}
}
```

GetLinksHelper.cs

```
public partial class SsoLinkHelper
    {
        public static SsoLinks GetLinks()
        {
            var ssoList = new SsoLinks();
            try
            {
                //search the index for all sso entries
                var searchResponse = _client.Search<SsoLink>(s => s
                    .Index(_ssoLinkIndex)
                    .Size(500)
                    .Query(q => q
                        .MatchAll()
                    )
                );
                if (searchResponse.Documents.Count == 0)
                {
                    return ssoList;
                }
                ssoList.Links.AddRange(searchResponse.Hits.Select(hit => new SsoLink() {Id = hit.Source.Id, Name = hit.Source.Name, Url = hit.Source.Url, Owner = hit.Source.Owner}));
                return ssoList;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.Error(e, "Web.Helpers.SsoLinkHelper.GetLinks");
                return ssoList;
            }
        }
    }
```

While debugging, It is failing at SsoLinks.Links.AddRange(etc). How can I add a new SsoLink to the ssoList for every item found in my query?

Edit: Here is a screenshot of the error while debugging.
[image: SSOError]

Comment: What is the error or exception you are getting ?

Comment: @kuldeep Object is not set to instance of an object, will post a screenshot as soon as I return to my computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The null reference exception looks like it comes from `ssoList.Links` being `null` when calling `AddRange` on it, so it needs to be initialized to a new instance of `List<SsoLink>` *before* calling `AddRange()`.

Comment: I see what you mean, but I need to return SsoLinks rather than a List<SsoLink> to the page so I can loop over it and grab the results, unless I am misunderstanding something.

Comment: The specific issue is a `NullReferenceException` because `ssoList.Links` is `null`. The model to pass to the view/page is not relevant to the exception thrown. Once the `NullReferenceException` is fixed, you can build an `SsoLinks` instance for your view

Answer (score 0):

Russ's answer led me down the right path, I ended up just needing to change my view to:

```
@model List<SharedModels.Models.SsoLink>
```

rather than

```
@model SharedModels.Models.SsoLink
```

and do away with the SsoLinks model.